# Server-side AssemblyScript: How to read a file?

Tags: server-side, assemblyscript, wasi

I'd like to write some server-side AssemblyScript that uses the WASI interface to read a file and process the contents.

I know that AssemblyScript and the ByteCode Alliance have recently had a falling out over the "openness" of the WASI standard, but I was hoping that they would still play nicely together...

I've found several AssemblyScript tools/libraries that appear to bridge this gap, and the one that seems the simplest to use is [`as-wasi`](https://github.com/jedisct1/as-wasi).  After following the installation instructions, I'm just trying to run the little demo app.

All the VSCode design time errors have disappeared, but the AssemblyScript compiler still barfs at the initial `import` statement.

```js
import "wasi"

import { Console, Environ } from "as-wasi/assembly";

// Create an environ instance
let env = new Environ();

// Get the HOME Environment variable
let home = env.get("HOME")!;

// Log the HOME string to stdout
Console.log(home);
```

Running `npm run asbuild` gives.

```bash
$ npm run asbuild

> file_reader@1.0.0 asbuild
> npm run asbuild:debug && npm run asbuild:release


> file_reader@1.0.0 asbuild:debug
> asc assembly/index.ts --target debug

ERROR TS6054: File '~lib/wasi.ts' not found.
   :
 1 │ import "wasi"
   │        ~~~~~~
   └─ in assembly/index.ts(1,8)

FAILURE 1 parse error(s)
```

The file `~lib/wasi.ts` does not exist and creating this file as a softlink pointing to the `index.ts` in the `./node_modules/as-wasi/assembly/` directory makes no difference.

Since the library is called `as-wasi` and not `wasi`, I've tried importing `as-wasi`, but this also fails.

I've also tried adapting `tsconfig.json` to include

```json
{
  "extends": "assemblyscript/std/assembly.json",
  "include": [
    "../node_modules/as-wasi/assembly/*.ts",
    "./**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

But this also has no effect.

What is causing `asc` to think that the required library should be in the directory called `~lib/` and how should I point it to the correct place?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question threw me in a bit of a rabbit hole, but I think I solved it.

So, apparently, after the wasi schism, AssemblyScript added the [wasi-shim](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/wasi-shim) repository, that you have to install as well:

```bash
npm install --save wasi-shim
```

The `import "wasi"` is no longer necessary after version 0.20 of AssemblyScript according to the same page, so you have to remove that import entirely. Also, be sure to add the `extends` to your `asconfig.json`, as recommended in the same `wasi-shim` page. Mine looks like this:

```js
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/@assemblyscript/wasi-shim/asconfig.json",
  "targets": {
    "debug": {
      "outFile": "build/debug.wasm",
      "textFile": "build/debug.wat",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "debug": true
    },
    "release": {
      "outFile": "build/release.wasm",
      "textFile": "build/release.wat",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "optimizeLevel": 3,
      "shrinkLevel": 0,
      "converge": false,
      "noAssert": false
    }
  },
  "options": {
    "bindings": "esm"
  }
}
```

It is just the generated original `asconfig.json` plus that `extends`.

Now the things got interesting. I got a compilation error:

```
ERROR TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'wasi_abort'.
      :
 1100 │ export function wasi_abort(
      │                 ~~~~~~~~~~
      └─ in ~lib/as-wasi/assembly/as-wasi.ts(1100,17)
    :
 19 │ export function wasi_abort(
    │                 ~~~~~~~~~~
    └─ in ~lib/wasi_internal.ts(19,17)
```

So I investigated, and it seems that `as-wasi` was exporting a symbol that was the same as a symbol exported by `wasi_shim`. No biggie, I went into `node_modules/as-wasi/`, and I renamed that function into `as_wasi_abort`. I did this also with the invokations of the function, namely three instances found in the `package.json` from `as-wasi`:

```js
{
    "asbuild:untouched": "asc assembly/index.ts -b build/untouched.wasm -t build/untouched.wat --use abort=as_wasi_abort --debug",
    "asbuild:small": "asc assembly/index.ts -b build/optimized.wasm -t build/optimized.wat --use abort=as_wasi_abort -O3z ",
    "asbuild:optimized": "asc assembly/index.ts -b build/optimized.wasm -t build/optimized.wat --use abort=as_wasi_abort -O3",
}
```

Having done all this, the package compiled and the example from [Wasm By Example](https://wasmbyexample.dev/examples/wasi-hello-world/wasi-hello-world.assemblyscript.en-us.html#) finally worked.

Your code should compile now, and I will try to make a pull request to all the places necessary so that the examples are updated, the code in `as-wasi` is updated, and so that nobody has to go through this again. Please comment if there are further problems.

Edit: It seems that I was right about the `wasi_abort` function being a problem. It is actually removed on the `as-wasi` repo, but the npm package is outdated. I asked in my pull request for it to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for getting to the bottom of this.  Its a bit of a pain, but it compiles and runs now